# want to show div with different timer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to show div with different class with different time.
for e.g
 my div has to show for 2000 ms class will be 'one' then
for div has to show for 4000 ms class will be be 'two', then div has to show for 3000 ms class will be 'three'.
i am using array to addClass with timer. but array short out from lower value to higher value. i dont want that. Please help me in this problem.

html code

```js
var text = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var timeleft =['5000','2000','4000','3000'];
            
$.each (timeleft, function(i, timeleft){
                
    setTimeout ( function(){
        $('#change').addClass(text[i]);
        $('#change').text(text[i]);
        console.log(text[i]);
                    
    }, timeleft);
})
```

```css
.one {
    background-color: red;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.two {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.three {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
.four {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
    color: white;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="change"> change</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`queue`](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [`delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) for this:

```js
var text = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var timeleft = ['5000', '2000', '4000', '3000'];

$.each(timeleft, function(i, timeleft) {
  $('#change')
    .queue(function() {
      $(this)
        .text(text[i])
        .addClass(text[i])
        .dequeue();
    })
    .delay(timeleft);
});
```

```css
.one {
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.three {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.four {
  background-color: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="" id="change">change</div>
```